# MLT Framework. How to add text or image watermark on the center of video and add zoomIn animation to it?

Tags: ffmpeg, mlt

Tried this:

```
-filter watermark:"welcome.jpg" in=0 out=320 composite.progressive=1 producer.align=centre composite.valign=middle composite.halign=center crop_to_fill=1 composite.geometry="0=0,0:80%x80%:0%;60=0,0:100%x100%:100%;260=0,0:120%x120%:100%;320=0,0:120%x120%:0%"
```

But it doesn't increase size of watermark, it just moves it to right bottom side...

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @medBouzid, that was long time ago and as i remember that was choppy, so zoom in looks not good at all... Few weeks ago  i've moved all video creation process to Adobe After effects, it's muuuuuch easier and you have much more flexibility, effects, etc =)

Comment: @medBouzid, i've moved to adobe after effects, it's much mooore easier to implement than mlt. On mlt it's choppy...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to animate a center zoom only using the watermark filter. But it is possible to animate a center zoom using the affine transition. You would need to use two tracks: one with the background video and another with the text to be animated. Here is an example:

```
melt color:blue in=0 out=320 -track welcome.jpg in=0 out=320 -transition affine valign=middle halign=center scale=1 fill=1 geometry="0=10%,10%:80%x80%:0%;60=0,0:100%x100%:100%;260=-10%,-10%:120%x120%:100%;320=-10%,-10%:120%x120%:0%"
```

The key is that the position of the watermark is relative to the left corner. So, in addition to animating the size, you also need to animate the x and y position as shown in the example.

Also note that the animation will interpolate the size and position for each frame - but the position is rounded to the nearest pixel. So the motion may not be smooth. That is a known limitation to the animation capabilities in MLT.

Comment: Yes, it works, but not smooth =(
Can i insert text not image to make such animation?